# install and configure sass and compass to use with the foundation

Tags: css, symfony, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Good installed foundation 5 just downloading and copying files

Now to move on veriaveis the need fondation have a .scss file however does not have anything on my Symfony2 project to use them

config.yml

```
filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        compass: ~
        sass: ~
```

base.html.twig

```
{% stylesheets "bundles/delivveweb/scss/*" filter="compass" %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

he is generating the css file however when you open the file contains the following error:

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
[message] An error occurred while running:
'/usr/bin/ruby' '/usr/bin/compass' 'compile' '/tmp' '--boring' '--config' '/tmp/assetic_compassl2wvYW' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/tmp/assetic_compassH8m6D9.scss'

Error Output:
/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- /usr/bin/compass (LoadError)
```

I hope someone can help me install it, if it were possible using composer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type in console:$`whereis compass` or `which compass`

Example output: - `compass: /usr/local/bin/compass`

Now in config.yml:

`filters:
        compass: 
            bin: /usr/local/bin/compass`